# MySQL - Counting Groups That Meet Certain Criteria

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

### Family

- ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT
- CountryOfResidence STRING

### Person

- ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT
- FamilyID INT FOREIGN KEY
- DOB DATE

I am trying to find the count of all the families by CountryOfResidence that contain somebody born before 1970.

I can't simply do a JOIN with `Person` and `Family` as that would give me the unique count of every person. I want the family to be counted only once when any person within the family is born before 1970.

Can someone help me craft this query? I feel like a subquery would accomplish what I am looking for, but I am afraid about the performance.

**EDIT**

Added SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b92e3/1/0

Expected results:

```
------------------------------- 
|CountryOfResidence | count(*)|
|-----------------------------| 
|Poland             | 1       | 
|USA                | 1       |
-------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` for this:

```
SELECT CountryOfResidence , COUNT(*)
FROM Family AS f
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Person AS p
              WHERE f.ID = p.FamilyID AND  Year(DOB) < 1970) 
GROUP BY CountryOfResidence
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `COUNT(DISTINCT Family.ID)` so you don't count all the duplicates due to the joins.

```
SELECT
  f.CountryOfResidence AS country,
  COUNT(DISTINCT f.ID) AS family_count_per_country
FROM Family AS f
INNER JOIN Person as p
  ON f.ID = p.FamilyID
WHERE p.DOB < '1970-01-01'
GROUP BY country
```

Answer (score 0):

No reason you can't use a JOIN here. It does seem odd to me though to have a country of residence tied to a family and not a person.

```
SELECT
  f.CountryOfResidence AS country,
  COUNT(f.ID) AS family_count_per_country
FROM Family AS f
INNER JOIN Person as p
  ON f.ID = p.FamilyID
WHERE p.DOB < '1970-01-01'
GROUP BY country
```

Comment: The problem is that a Family can have more than one members being born before 1970. In this case a `JOIN` will return duplicate records.

Comment: The `GROUP BY` statement handles this de-duping.  You are only going to get one record in result set per family/country combination

Comment: Your query did not return the expected results - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b92e3/2/0